# java prevent components from resizing on frame resize

Tags: java, swing

So I have a bunch of components that are laid out in a JPanel to make a GUI that lets the user input characters. However, when the JFrame is resized, the components go all crazy and shrink a ton. Is there a way to fix this, or should I just disable resizing the JFrame. I basically want it to keep all the components the same size and chop off the components when the window gets too small. I've seen people say that GridBagLayout can fix this, but I still can't figure out how to do it.

Code:

```
public class CharacterWrapper extends JPanel {
    private int currentID = 0;
    private JFrame parent;
    private ArrayList<CharacterInput> inputSlots = new ArrayList<CharacterInput>();

    /**
     * 
     */
    public CharacterWrapper(JFrame parent) {
        this.parent = parent;

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        JButton deleteButton = new JButton("Delete");
        deleteButton.addActionListener(e -> {
            deleteInput();
            parent.pack();
        });

        JButton addButton = new JButton("Add");
        addButton.addActionListener(e -> {
            addInput();
            parent.pack();
        });

        add(addButton);
        add(deleteButton);
        addInput();
        addInput();
        addInput();

    }

    public void addInput() {
        inputSlots.add(new CharacterInput(currentID++, this));
        add(inputSlots.get(inputSlots.size() - 1));
        revalidate();
    }

    public void deleteInput() {
        if (inputSlots.size() > 3) {
            Component c = inputSlots.remove(inputSlots.size() - 1);
            remove(c);
            revalidate();
            currentID--;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setContentPane(new CharacterWrapper(frame));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

And more code:

```
public class CharacterInput extends JComponent{
    private int id;
    private CharacterWrapper parent;
    /**
     * 
     */
    public CharacterInput(int id, CharacterWrapper parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
    this.id = id;
    setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

    JTextField textField = new JTextField();
    textField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter(){
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) { 
            if (textField.getText().length() >= 1) 
                e.consume(); 
        } 
    });

    textField.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(35, 35));
    JLabel label = new JLabel(id + "", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    add(textField);
    add(label);
    this.setBackground(Color.RED);
    }

}
```

Comment: You might be able to use a `GridBagLayout`, but you'd have to play around with the fill and weight constraints

Answer (score 1):

I will recommened to use GridLayout or GridBagLayout only if you have dynamic components addition like adding JTextField when user presses a button.

I will suggest you use BorderLayout. It is simple and you can play easily.

For example: You have 8 components to be placed on JFrame but BorderLayout has only 5 sides. So add a parent panel with BorderLayout, add another JPanel(with BorderLayout) to North of parent panel. This way you can add 9 components altogether.

Major advantage of using BorderLayout is resizing. When you resize, your components will also resize accordingly.

Hope this will help you. :-)

Answer (score 0):

May be this would help a bit. Use `GridBagConstraints` in this way:

```
public void addInput() {
gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
gbc.gridx = i;
gbc.gridy = 0;
gbc.weightx = 1;
gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
inputSlots.add(new CharacterInput(currentID++, this));
add(inputSlots.get(inputSlots.size() - 1), gbc);
repaint();
revalidate();
```

using `gbc.weightx = 1` will help you in removing shrinking of components.